# How to use "modern" CMake exported targets in the context of existing libraries

Tags: module, cmake, cmake-modules

I'm updating a (very old) find-module of a library. So the situation is an existing shared library which uses CMake itself. Users might already have this installed somewhere, in package repos or whatever.

Now they want to use this. The good way would be

```
find_package(Foo REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(MyProject Foo::Foo)
```

So thats the goal.

The question is: How would a good find_package-Config or -Module look like which allows this 2-liner to work? It should meet these 2 requirements:

- Allow a CMake version to **use** the library older than the one used to **build** it
- Enforce e.g C++11 mode. In a Find-Module one can set the C++11 requirement based on the version (`cxx_std_11` (CMake 3.8+), `cxx_alias_templates` (CMake 3.1+), `check_cxx_source_compiles` with C++11 code and a warning for older CMakes)

There are 2 ways of doing that:

1. Update the find-module to define an imported library `Foo::Foo` and set it up correctly (using properties) and be nice to also set `FOO_INCLUDE_DIR` and `FOO_LIBRARIES` for old CMake w/o targets.
   This is pretty easy: Just use `find_path` and `find_library`, set up the imported target and be done. Works forwards and backwards compatible so even the old versions would be found.

**Usage:**
The user copies (the most recent) `FindFoo.cmake` to its project into e.g. `cmake/Modules` and points `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to it, or copy `FindFoo.cmake` to some CMake default path.

2. Listening to [Daniel Pfeiffer](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2017/blob/master/05-19-2017_friday/effective_cmake__daniel_pfeifer__cppnow_05-19-2017.pdf) and [Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/exporting.html) which says `If you are the library author, don't make a Find<mypackage>.cmake script!` So we export and install targets.
   This is a bit messy. Following changes are required:

   - Add `EXPORTS FooTargets` and `INCLUDES DESTINATION include` to `install(TARGETS` (see Pfeiffer #24) which basically just defines an export. (I don't really see, why I would want to create an extra name for something that already has a name. Why can't the below command not simply refer to a target?)
   - Add `install(EXPORT FooTargets NAMESPACE Foo:: DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo)` which would create a `FooTargets.cmake` in `<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/lib/cmake/Foo` that defines a target `Foo::Foo` with (hopefully) all its dependencies
   - Add "something" creating `FooConfigVersion.cmake` possibly by using `write_basic_package_version_file` that, to my understanding, hard-codes the version to that file
   - Create a `FooConfig.cmake` that may use `find_dependency` to search for libraries that Foo depends on and includes `FooTargets.cmake`
   - Install `FooConfig.cmake` and `FooConfigVersion.cmake` to `lib/cmake/Foo`
   - modify `target_include_directories` to use separate `BUILD_INTERFACE` and `INSTALL_INTERFACE` paths

**Usage:**
`find_package` automatically finds the `FooConfig.cmake` and `FooConfigVersion.cmake` when `Foo` is searched for.

So the Config-Module should be preferred but problems I see are:

- The process looks more complicated
- It cannot be used to enable users to find older versions of the library (that did not use this approach)
- It excludes all (library-)users with older CMake (2.8.11 is probably the minimum required here)
- It requires a newer CMake version to build the library itself
- The C++11 requirement seems to be very hard to encode

So can we solve the requirements with a CMake-Config? An answer should provide a solution or at least a well grounded "impossible". It should also address the problems outlined at the end.

Final Note: I guess this makes a nice wiki-entry if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well-formulated question and answers for it can be easily treated as "wiki-entry". Currently, I see the only question in your post about CMake version-independent usage requirement in export approach. But this question is near at the end of the post; the rest of the post is quite a long "introduction". Could you reorganize the post, so the question will be near the **beginning**? Otherwise, it is too hard to find a real question. Also, current title is very generic; it is better when a title reflects a problem, not a problem area.

Comment: Better now? If you find a better title please edit it. I specifically want this as a wiki-entry (or a base for one) as I think it covers everything from goal, usage instructions to problems and will hopefully even have solutions for them.

Comment: Yes, the question post becomes better now, thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I'm having trouble reading the question still: Its internal order is unclear, it has forward- references, it uses ambiguous pronouns occasionally, etc.

Comment: I structured it a bit better. It's not easy but I think this is due to the question being not easy to answer.